# How to automate Long Press action in an iOS app using app?

Tags: java, selenium, appium

I am trying to automate long-press action on a native ios app.
My appium version is 1.19.
I have tried the following code that is shared on the Appium website.

```
    TouchActions action = new TouchActions(driver);
    action.longPress(element);
    action.perform();
```

Please share the code that runs.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. Found that it needs a release action as well.

```
action.longPress(element);
action.release();
action.perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IOSElement iosElement = (IOSElement) driver.findElement(element);
TouchAction action = new TouchAction(driver);
PointOption pointOption = PointOption.point(iosElement.getLocation());
action.longPress(pointOption).perform();
```

You can do it like this.